# How to list the files commited using git/git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I created a hotfix using git flow. Now I did that a while ago and committed few files to the development environment. Then I switched to another feature. Now I wish to see the list of files I changed/committed against this hotfix.

Could any one please give the command on how to list the files.

Comment: `git whatchanged <hash_of_hotfix>`?

Comment: @GaryFixler, in git-flow a 'hotfix' refers to a whole branch, which by definition branches off from master. Hence my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the hotfix branch and do

```
git diff --name-only master
```

That will show you all the files that have changed in the hotfix branch.

```
git diff --name-status master
```

will do the same but with an A for Added, M for Modified and D for Deleted to give you a more detailed overview of the changes.